# MultipleOutputs vs SideEffectFile

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to know the advantage/differences between MultipleOutputs vs FSDataOutputStream vs Task Side Effect File for creating different output files?

a. Using MultipleOutputs:

```
MultipleOutputs mos;

void configure()
{
    mos.new MultipleOutputs(conf);
}

reduce()
{
    mos.getCollector("desired_path", reporter).collect(new Text(key), new Text(val));
}
```

b. Using FSDataOutputream, we write the output to the desired path in the file system like this:

```
    void configure()
   {
       fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
   }


    void reduce()
   {

       Path op = "/custom_path";
   FSDataOutputStream dst = fs.create(op);
   dst.writeBytes(t+" "+uidi+" "+str_sizeval); 
   }
```

c. Using task side effect files. Here, we write the output to the path retured by FileOutputFormat.getWorkOutputPath(), using FSDataOutputStream as above, instead of using a custom desired path.

Which is the best way to write the desired output to the path other than the output path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a & c are more or less the same thing and have the distinct advantage over b in that they are managed by an output committer.

Using b combined with speculative execution means you'll either get an error (two things trying to write to the same file), or potentially corrupted results.

a & c don't have this problem as they are outputting to a temporary task attempt folder on HDFS, whose contents are moved to the actual output folder when the task attempt is committed (and hence you won't get problems with speculative execution).

a is also a better option than c, as it managed file uniqueness - each file is named with an additional task ID (for your example 'desired_path-r-00000'). If you were to use c, and have two reducers writing to the same fail name, the last task to commit will overwrite the contents of the first task committed or you'll get an error (i'm not sure which).

So in short, a is the best option.